# @RestControllerAdvice paired with @ExceptionHandler is not returning a JSON from a data class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, exception

I'm writing a small app using Kotlin with Spring Boot 3. I wanted to have a nice exception handling, so I have created a class annotated with `@RestControllerAdvice`, having a couple of methods annotated with `@ExceptionHandler`. I have created a `data class` to store the returned body data:

```
data class ApiError(
    private val requestUri: String? = null,
    private val status: Int = 0,
    private val statusText: String? = null,
    private val createdAt: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Warsaw")),
    private val errorMessage: String? = null,
)
```

The rest is quite simple:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
class ControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException::class)
    fun methodNotSupportedException(
        exception: HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException,
        request: HttpServletRequest,
    ): ResponseEntity<ApiError> {
        println(buildApiError(request, HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, exception))
        return ResponseEntity(
            buildApiError(request, HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, exception),
            HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED,
        )
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException::class)
    fun notFoundExceptionHandler(
        exception: NotFoundException,
        request: HttpServletRequest,
    ): ResponseEntity<ApiError> {
        println(buildApiError(request, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, exception))
        return ResponseEntity(
            buildApiError(request, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, exception),
            HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
        )
    }

    private fun buildApiError(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        httpStatus: HttpStatus,
        throwable: Throwable,
    ): ApiError {
        return ApiError(
            requestUri = request.requestURI,
            status = httpStatus.value(),
            statusText = httpStatus.reasonPhrase,
            errorMessage = throwable.message,
        )
    }
}
```

And there is this (do not worry about the quality of this code, it is just for testing purposes.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(
    path = ["/hello"],
)
class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/{name}", produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    private fun hello(@PathVariable name: String): ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> {

        // this is a forced exception so the @ExceptionHandlers could handle them.
        if (name.lowercase() == "stefan") throw NotFoundException("Name not found!")
        return ResponseEntity.ok(mapOf("Hello" to "$name!"))
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run the app and send a `GET` request to `http://localhost:8080/hello/myrealname I just receive a tiny object:

```
{
    "Hello": "myrealname"
}
```

But when I either POST to this endpoint or GET with name "stefan" to trigger the exception, I have received a proper status code, either 500 or 404, but the body of my response was empty!

Later on I tried to return a string or a map instead of my `ApiError` class, everything was fine, the body was there, either a map or a string. But when I want to return an instance of `ApiError`, the body is empty. Bare `'{}'`. Is there something wrong with my object? This is not the first time I have worked with exception handling in a controller advice class, and I have never had a situation like this.

What could be the possible cause of this problem? Is there a better, more Kotlin-ish approach to this? Any extension methods I have no idea about maybe?

Honest thank You for any clues :)

Comment: Why have you set your ApiError fields private ? Have you tried making them public instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you defined all properties in your `ApiError` data class as private they are not visible to Jackson ObjectMapper serializer which is included in spring-web.

So to solve your issue you just need *to remove **private** modifier* like this:

```
data class ApiError(
    val requestUri: String? = null,
    val status: Int = 0,
    val statusText: String? = null,
    val createdAt: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Warsaw")),
    val errorMessage: String? = null,
)
```

Comment: That was it! You're a genius!